# Can't change virtualmin / webmin password

Tags: password, virtualmin

I want to change the Webmin login password. The one that you use to log in with when you connect to 10000 port. I have tried several ways. The password will change but at the login, I can only log in with my old password. How can I change this? Here are the ways that I change the password:

> Login into Webmin interface.
> Click on the option 'System' in the left sidebar of Webmin.
> Select the option 'Change Password' and you will be able to see a screen with all of the users listed.
> Select the user which you want to change the password from the list.

Another way that changed my PHPMyAdmin password but not the Webmin login:

> Login into Webmin interface. Click on the option 'Edit Virtual Server' in the right sidebar of Virtualmin. In the 'Configurable settings' section change the 'Administration password'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to change the password using SSH. I'm using Ubuntu so I used this command

```
/usr/share/webmin/changepass.pl /etc/webmin root NEWPASSWORD
```

during this process I got `Can't locate ./acl/md5-lib.pl at /usr/share/webmin/changepass.pl line 6.` Error and after I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66909031/cant-locate-acl-md5-lib-pl-at-usr-share-webmin-changepass-pl) I was able to solve it.